# SQLite em memory com dapper gera erro de tabela não existente

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sqlite, sqlite3, dapper

Tenho o seguinte código para criação da tabela:

```
            string query = @"CREATE TABLE GVP_USERS_TAGS(
                            ID integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                            DATEINS datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (DATETIME('now')),
                            NAME varchar(250) NOT NULL,
                            OWNER integer NOT NULL,
                            USER_ID integer NOT NULL,
                            PRODUCT_ID integer NOT NULL,
                            TYPE_ID integer NOT NULL,
                            VALUE varchar(250) NOT NULL,
                            PRODUCT_TYPE_ID integer NOT NULL,
                            Updated_Row timestamp NOT NULL,
                            MOVIE_TYPE_ID integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                            PIN_REQUIRED integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
                        )";
        return await queryExecutor.ExecuteAsync(query);
```

depois uso o seguinte código:

```
var countQuery = $"SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM GVP_USERS_TAGS NOLOCK {where}";
int count = await queryExecutor.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(countQuery, parameters);
```

é lançado a seguinte exceção:

```
SQL logic error\\r\\nno such table: GVP_USERS_TAGS\
```

detalhe quando uso em filesystem funciona.

Comment: consegue colocar um try no  seu  queryExecutor.ExecuteAsync(query); ? pois o erro é categorico em  afirma  que a  tabela  não existe  então o problema está em  cria-la

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando `_connection.Open();`.